# Save Differences with Entity ID

Tags: javers

i want to save the difference of two entities. the old entity has a id witch is not null. the new one has an id with a null value so i compare them as valueObject. The problem is that ValueChange does save the differences but not the id of the old one. How can ich achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

For Entities, Id property cannot be null, so you need to map this class as ValueObject. If so, Id property is treated as regular property and it not goes to GlobalId of this object.